# Select the highest order delivered

Tags: sql, oracle

Following is my output:

```
MONTH STAF STAFFNAME            TOTAL_ORDER_DELIVERED
===== ==== ==================== =====================
JAN   S009 Theresina Ertelt                         1
FEB   S015 Lonna Charker                            1
MAR   S003 Suzi Maccari                             2
MAR   S010 Zacharie Witty                           1
MAR   S020 Abbie Gosnoll                            1
MAR   S017 Renee Alston                             1
AUG   S006 Falito Ollerton                          1
AUG   S017 Renee Alston                             1
AUG   S003 Suzi Maccari                             1
OCT   S003 Suzi Maccari                             3
OCT   S020 Abbie Gosnoll                            2
```

What I want is:

```
MONTH STAF STAFFNAME            TOTAL_ORDER_DELIVERED
===== ==== ==================== =====================
JAN   S009 Theresina Ertelt                         1
FEB   S015 Lonna Charker                            1
MAR   S003 Suzi Maccari                             2
AUG   S006 Falito Ollerton                          1
AUG   S017 Renee Alston                             1
AUG   S003 Suzi Maccari                             1
OCT   S003 Suzi Maccari                             3
```

I want to select the highest result based on the month but can't figure what to do. Here are my query in SQL:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM receivedDate),'mm'),'MON') AS Month,
       d.staffID, staffname, count(deliveryID) AS Total_Order_Delivered
FROM delivery d, deliverystaff s
WHERE (d.staffid = s.staffid)
AND (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM receivedDate) = 2020)
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM d.receivedDate),d.staffid, staffname 
ORDER BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM d.receivedDate),count(deliveryID) desc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `RANK` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM receivedDate), 'mm'), 'MON') AS Month,
           EXTRACT(MONTH FROM d.receivedDate) AS month_num,
           d.staffID, staffname, COUNT(deliveryID) AS Total_Order_Delivered,
           RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM d.receivedDate), d.staffid, staffname
                        ORDER BY COUNT(deliveryID) DESC) rnk
    FROM delivery d
    INNER JOIN deliverystaff s ON d.staffid = s.staffid
    WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM receivedDate) = 2020
    GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM d.receivedDate), d.staffid, staffname
)

SELECT Month, staffID, staffname, Total_Order_Delivered
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY month_num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tim's answer is fine.  However, I strongly encourage you to make some changes to the query.

First, for the `where` clause don't use `extract()`.  Use direct date comparisons.  Second, include the year and month in the aggregation.  Then, be sure that you qualify *all* column references.

That allows you to do:

```
SELECT sd.*
FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(d.receivedDate, 'YYYY-MON') AS Month_year,
             s.staffID, s.staffname, COUNT(*) AS Total_Order_Delivered,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TO_CHAR(d.receivedDate, 'YYYY-MON') ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum,
              MIN(d.receiveddate) as min_receiveddate
      FROM deliverystaff s JOIN
           delivery d
           ON d.staffid = s.staffid
      WHERE d.receivedDate >= DATE '2020-01-01' AND 
            d.receivedDate < DATE '2021-01-01'
      GROUP BY TO_CHAR(d.receivedDate, 'YYYY-MON') AS Month,
               s.staffID, s.staffname 
     ) sd
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY min_receiveddate;
```

In addition to the above, this allows you to order the results *chronologically* and works if you extend the time frame to more than one year.